# Folding Paper and Angles Question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

We are trying to solve this problem asking us to look for a certain angle involving a paper being folded.

Here's the problem:

On a square-shaped paper ABCD, folds the paper according to line EF to make an equal half.  Again, generates ab equal half ti each side of the paper, where A and B meet each other.  As shown in the image below, what is X?

[image]

X° in our solution results in 45° but in the answer key it's 75° and we can't seem to find the reason why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you arrive at $45^{\circ}$? (You most likely carried out calculations by accidentally treating FD as CD, but you might have done something else.) You should explain your working. You will then receive more helpful answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  We began our solution by assuming AD = CD, and this makes angle GDC 60°. Let's say that midpoint between A and E is H.  Isn't angle EHG also 60° ?  Then, we also got angle ADH as 15° so angle AHD is 75°.  X° is then 180° - 60° - 75° = 45°.  Hopefully our solution is not too confusing

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see,[image: geometry for solution.] The answer is $75^°$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyse your working:

"Hi, thanks for your reply. We began our solution by assuming AD = CD, and this makes angle GDC 60°. Let's say that midpoint between A and E is H. Isn't angle EHG also 60° ? Then, we also got angle ADH as 15° so angle AHD is 75°. X° is then 180° - 60° - 75° = 45°."

1. Because $AC$ = $CD$, after folding the corners, you obtain an equilateral triangle, so $\angle GDC$ = $60^\circ$ as you said.
2. We denote the midpoint of $AE$ by $H$. What is $\angle EHG$? First, from 1., we see that $\angle GDF = 30^\circ$. We also know that $\angle GDH = 90^\circ$, as the original paper is square. Using "angles on a line add to $180^\circ$", we have $\angle EGH = 180^\circ-90^\circ-30^\circ = 60^\circ$. The sum of angles in a triangle add to $180^\circ$, so $\angle EHG = 180^\circ - 60^\circ - 90^\circ = 30^\circ \neq 60^\circ$.
3. The rest of your argument is fine.

In summary, you need to calculate $\angle EHG$ more carefully. You'll see that everything works out now.